# How to navigate to desktop when desktop is on seperate drive

Tags: cmd.exe

So, I moved my `Desktop` to `D:` drive is there any way to directly point cmd window to desktop folder without first doing `pushd D:`.

Comment: you can just type `d:` to change to the D drive. There is no variable set by default that points to your desktop though. You can create one, but it will be a custom one.

Comment: @LPChip so navigating to D: drive has to be manual then...I see

Comment: That is an option, or you create a script that navigates to the folder, and give that an easy to type name.

Comment: Right-click the Desktop. The context-menu may have an option named "Open in Terminal" that will open PowerShell with the desktop folder.

Answer (score 3):

The following solution work if you are using the Windows menu to open CMD :

- Use Windows key to open Windows menu
- Search "cmd"
- Right click on the command prompt
- Open the file location
- Right click on the CMD shortcut
- Properties
- In shortcut tab, set the value "Start in" to "D:

Now cmd will start in "D:" if you run it by using the shortcut in Windows menu.

You can also copy this shortcut on your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

At the command prompt, type:
`C:\> cd /D "D:\<path-to-desktop\"`

Also try;
<kbd>Winkey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>
`cmd /k cd /D "D:\<path-to-desktop\"` *(untested)*

ref:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd