# Change CMD/Git Bash home direcroty to C:\Users\Phil

Tags: windows-10, command-line

My home directory in CMD/Git Bash is a network drive `H:\`. I want my directory to be the same as my user profile `C:\Users\Phil`. I don't want to have a network drive be my home directory because it's much slower. How can I change this?

**When I enter `cd ~` I want it to go to `C:\Users\Phil` instead of the network drive.**

Comment: This could help you : https://superuser.com/questions/1735979/how-to-navigate-to-desktop-when-desktop-is-on-seperate-drive/1736002#1736002

Comment: @S.Brottes that only changes where it starts. If I enter `cd` it will go back to `H:` drive. Also `.ssh` and `.bashrc` will continue to be searched for on `H:` drive.

Comment: Here seems to be exactly your problem https://superuser.com/questions/246731/how-do-i-change-homedrive-homepath-and-homeshare-in-windows-xp

Comment: @S.Brottes great! `net use h: /delete` worked. Home drive in Git Bash is now `C:\Users\Phil` and `C:\WINDOWS\system32` in CMD which I'm fine with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: This removed my `H:` drive but I'm still able to access the drive with the network path. Make sure you record the network path of the drive before using this command.

In command prompt enter `net use h: /delete` replace `h:` with the current home directory you wish to change. This will remove your network drive. **Now when I type cd it goes to `C:\Users\Phil`**

Credit to S. Brottes for finding this answer.